# When creating a PDF from a google sheet using a script editor, the image is not uploaded completely (just 80%)

Tags: google-apps-script

When I am creating a PDF with a script editor, I use the usual ''=IMAGE(H8,1)'' function. In cell H8 there is an image with URLs format. After creating the pdf, all the data is properly created (text, tables), unfortunately, the picture is not uploaded completely (just 80%).
I have used the features utilities.sleep() but the same problem is still there.
Is there any other way to fix this error or should I create a separate image upload function?

I'm new here and I have just start with the script editor so please be understanding if I ask for something simple.

Comment: Thank you for the hint.
Is it possible to make UrlFetchApp read the URL link from a cell? Here I have to give a URL but I would like to have a possibility to change the image URL in a cell not to give it into the formula  UrlFetchApp. 
In another word: URL from sheet 1 in A2 is moving to sheet 2 to H8 (now it is shown us an image not url) and then I make PDF with this image.

Comment: That's what I did, but unfortunately, the image is not uploaded completely.

Comment: I thought that when I saw your question, when your situation can be replicated, it might lead to the solution and workaround. So, in order to correctly understand and replicate your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet and your current script for replicating your issue?

Comment: Sorry for delay but I was quite busy but now I have time for new script passion :)
I split it because it's too long

Comment: function newpdf() {
   
   var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
   var sheetA = ssA.getSheetByName('ACTIV Tasks')
   var sheetC = ssA.getSheetByName('PDF_template')
     
   var step;                                        
   for (step = 0; step < 100; step++) {               
    
     // pętla
     
   var linia = 101-step
   var tick = sheetA.getRange('M'+line).getValue()     
   var Email =  sheetA.getRange('A'+line).getValue()                                  
   var Name =  sheetA.getRange('B'+line).getValue()
   var PictureCar =  sheetA.getRange('W'+line).getValue()

Comment: if (tick == "1"){                                
     
     var formatedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd MMMM yyyy  -  HH:mm")
     var pdfName = "Invoice : "+Name+"  - "+formatedDate;
       
 // 
   var WpiszEmail = sheetC.getRange('F6')
   var WpiszName = sheetC.getRange('U6')
   var WpiszPicCar = sheetC.getRange('H8')
     //
     
     WpiszEmail.setValue(Email);
     WpiszName.setValue(Name);
     WpiszPicCar.setValue(PictureCar);
     
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     //

Comment: var sheetName = "PDF_template";
    var folderID = "5i"; // Folder id to save in a folder.
    var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
    //-Copy whole spreadsheet
     
    var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("Temp_file_for_PDF", folder)) 
    //-delete redundant sheets

Comment: var sheetName = "PDF_template"  
   var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
   for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
   if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
   destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
   }
   }
     
   var NewUrl = destSpreadsheet.getId();

Comment: var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(NewUrl).getAs("application/pdf"); 
   blob.setName(pdfName+'.pdf');
   var dossier = DriveApp.getFolderById('59');
   dossier.createFile(blob); 
   //
   
   DriveApp.getFilesByName('Temp_file_for_PDF').next().setTrashed(true);

   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Pdf is ready : " + pdfName);   
  
    }
   
   else {

Comment: }
   }
   //    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Finish work", 'INFO SKRYPT');